# Disassembler Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, disassembly

I am using debugging in Visual Studio and ***disassembler*** window to get the instruction code in hex, but when the main call a function (as Fig.1), the function instructions appear in a sperate section (as Fig. 2)
Is there any way to show the function instructions appears as a part of the main?

***main section in dissasembler window***
[image: main section idisassemblerer window]

***function section in dissasembler window***
[image: function section in dissasembler window]
Thanks,

Comment: Hard to guess what you are talking about, I *think* you want the function to get inlined.  That is not going to happen until you build the Release build, right now you are looking at unoptimized Debug built code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `mov eax, 0CCCCCCCCh` it seems you're working with a Debug build.

In Debug mode Visual Studio does not inline any function by default.

You can switch to Release mode or enable function inlining in compiler settings (C/C++ - Optimization - Inline Function Expansion) and the call to `fun()` will probably get inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Disassembly is always going to be a separate window, there are options on the context menu for the disassembly window that allows you to control what is shown (source code or not, or instruction addresses or not, for example).

Comment: Yes, I know, but my concern is the order of the instruction code, i.e. I want the function code as its a part of the main

Comment: But it isn't a part of the main.  As the disassembly shows, it's a `call` to another function with its own local variables and stack operations.  Not the same exact instructions as if the code were actually in `main`

Comment: @noor: the compiler often doesn't know whether there are more callers. That hinders inlining